# html and css is not showing text wrap Trouble?

Tags: html, css

How can I make this text wrap in the next line when it overflows?
I have tried all the options line overflow-break, and word break but neither of them worked.

```css
.first_product {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 4px black;
}

.pdiv {
  width: 23%;
  height: 90%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 8px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.pimg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.pname {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="first_product">
  <div class="pdiv">
    <a href=""><img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="" class="pimg"></a>
    <div class="pname">ggggggggggggggggggggggcccccccccccccccccccccccccgggggg</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Looking at your HTML code, you have a missing closing `<\div>` tag; that might well be the reason why your styles do not work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

remove

```
.first_product{
    width:100%;
    height:70%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
     white-space: nowrap; <------- this
     box-shadow:0px 1px 2px 4px black;
}
```

white space nowrap is the one that controls the new lines

if you need the other divs not to wrap then add only to pname

```
.pname{
width:100%;
height:20%;
overflow-wrap:break-word;
background-color:green;
    white-space: normal; <---- this

}
```